# "WARNING: reaching max number of iterations" during tuning of parameters for linear SVM

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, svm

I have this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mirbektoktogaraev/should-this-loan-be-approved-or-denied from which I have removed all instances where NewExist = 1 and all instances containing NA values. I have also removed the ChgOffPrinGr column, so I have 161,732 instances and 25 variables left. I need to apply a series of Machine Learning models with MIS_Status as the target variable. To achieve this, I am not using all the variables as predictors because, obviously, I need to eliminate all those variables containing "future" values, i.e., values that cannot be known in advance. Therefore, I have 161,732 instances with 10 variables: State (factor), Bank (factor), NAICS (factor), UrbanRural (factor), RevLineCr (factor), LowDoc (factor), Term (double), NoEmp (double), FranchiseCode (factor), GrAppv (double), MIS_Status (factor, target).

The first thing I did was preprocess the dataset to apply the algorithms (so I created the recipe) with this code:

```
selected_columns <- c("State", "Bank", "NAICS", "UrbanRural", "RevLineCr", "LowDoc", "Term", "NoEmp", "FranchiseCode", "GrAppv", "MIS_Status")

df_selected <- SBAnational[selected_columns]

low_var_cols <- caret::nzv(df_selected)

df_no_zv <- df_selected[, -low_var_cols]

set.seed(123)  

split_index <- createDataPartition(df_no_zv$MIS_Status, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- df_no_zv[split_index, ]
test_data <- df_no_zv[-split_index, ]

data_recipe <- recipe(MIS_Status ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
  step_center(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_scale(all_numeric(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes(), one_hot = TRUE)

data_prep <- prep(data_recipe, training = train_data)

train_processed <- bake(data_prep, new_data = train_data)
test_processed <- bake(data_prep, new_data = test_data)
```

At the end of this iteration, I find myself with a training set of 113,214 instances and 4,382 variables.

At this point, I decided to first apply the linear SVM by tuning the parameters. The code looks like this:

```
svm_model <- svm(MIS_Status ~ ., data = train_processed, kernel = "linear")

tune_result <- tune(svm, MIS_Status ~ ., data = train_processed, kernel = "linear", ranges = list(cost = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)))
```

The issue is that the tuning has been running for more than 12 hours, and I've encountered this warning message 6 times:

```
> tune_result <- tune(svm, MIS_Status ~ ., data = train_processed, kernel = "linear", ranges = list(cost = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)))

WARNING: reaching max number of iterations

WARNING: reaching max number of iterations

WARNING: reaching max number of iterations

WARNING: reaching max number of iterations

WARNING: reaching max number of iterations

WARNING: reaching max number of iterations
```

Can you give me some suggestions to simplify everything?

(MacBook Air M2 16GB 512GB)

Comment: I would venture a guess that there are few combinations of factors that lack enough data to find an optimal solution.  I would suggest filtering down your initial dataset to remove some of your factor levels for an initial trial as oppose to going for broke with 4000+ variables on the first go around.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement your suggestions.